# VBA in Excel: Screen freezes for a few seconds after consecutive copies and pastes

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a simple code to replicate the problem:

```
Sub test()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    For i = 1 To 1000
        Range("A" & i).Copy Destination:=Range("B" & i)
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

If I execute the above program block, after the program is completed, the screen will freeze for about 5 seconds before releasing the control to the user.

If I change the number of times of copies (from 1000 to other values in the code), I can see that the freezing time is proportional to the number of copies.

Is this the problem of my computer, or it actually happens on every computer? How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you sure it freezes after, not during?

Comment: Yes, I tried to add a user form that will pop up after the loop. I can only close the user form after 5 seconds.

Comment: Might be about calculations, but then it should not really depend on number of iterations because it would recalculate after each one. Try switching off automatic calculations too though.

Comment: Yes I have tried that as well. But still the same :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is an issue isolated to your computer, as I encounter a similar lag time in the calculations (proportional to upper bound of iteration, as you've rightly pointed out). Its just a consequence of iterating a copy and/or paste unfortunately, as this (I find) takes longer to do in VBA than most things (and ultimately slows down code). What might be worth a try is the following:

```
Sub test()
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
   For i = 1 To 1000
       'Range("A" & i).Copy Destination:=Range("B" & i)
       Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
   Next
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Technically it does the exact same thing as your code, but without copying. I'm not sure how this will relate back to your actual work (as opposed to this example) but I find it is quicker to run on my machine.

Basically, my point is that Copy and/or Pasting in big iterations is just slow in VBA full stop, so my advice is to avoid where possible. Good link to an article on it below :)

http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/SpeedingUpVBACode.htm

Comment: Yes indeed copying in this way is faster, it works much better now :) thanks